# PySpark read multi parquet with same schema but multi type in columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My problem is pretty simple but I cannot find a great solution. I have a lot of order parquet. I read all of them with this :

```py
df = spark.read.option(
    'mergeSchema',
    True).parquet(*list_order).select(
        'at',
        'order_id',
        'items')
```

This work great if the schemas are the same.
But in my new data one of the column "quantity" we change the type String to Float. This mean that this read code does not work anymore. It create an error like that :

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to merge fields 'quantity' and 'quantity'. Failed to merge incompatible data types string and double
```

Do you know how I can merge this multi type column ? I'll pref to not regenerate my 4 year history of parquet (will take to much time on prod)

Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by providing the schema manually using the `.schema(your_schema)` property

```py
old_df = spark.read.parquet('old_files')
old_schema = old_df.schema

# Make changes in old_schema and declare it as new_schema

df = spark.read.schema(new_schema).parquet(your_files)
```

The idea is that you are reading your data as SCHEMA_ON_READ instead of the conventional SCHEMA_ON_WRITE approach in Databases.
So if you tell spark to read data with a given schema, it will stick to it.

Or you can always read your data as 2 data frames. Cast the columns and union them.

Comment: Yes I saw this solution but I have a big schema (differing from one to others) :
pretty much like this : https://jpst.it/2RYdH

And I have a lot of file (1000>)

Comment: the link isn't working for me

Comment: I don't need all the columns but can't select before reading

Comment: It wouldn't matter if the schema is huge. You will just have to change the types of the column in variable old_schema to your desired type. After defining the schema you can use the select statement and it will only read the columns in the select query as spark will optimize the query plan

Comment: https://justpaste.it/4dgbe